# Can I change properties values for multiple fields at once in SSDT 2012?

Tags: ssas, sql-server-data-tools, cube

In SQL Server Data Tool in Visual Studio 2012, is it possible to change a Property for multiple fields at once? For example, can I change the NumberFormat property or the DisplayFolder property for multiple measures at once?